# How could I update a variable to change its value? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

As the question says, How would I be able to make a variable take a new value when the button is clicked?

Ex.

```
var count = 0

    goal2View.setOnClickListener{
        goalCount.text = count.plus(1).toString()
    }
```

Now I want *count* to be equal to 1 so when the next onClickListener is executed the *goalCount.text* would print a value of 2. Also *goalCount* is the textView in my activity.

```
    goal3View.setOnClickListener{
        goalCount.text = count.plus(1).toString()
    }
```

Now the *goalCount* should be 2.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you just asking how to increment an integer in Kotlin?

Comment: `goalCount.text = (++count).toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to add to the `goalCount.text`'s value without actually incrementing the variable `count`. So the value will be 1 on every click instead of an accurate count.

The easy solution is to increment the count before assigning the value of `goalCount.text`.

```
var count = 0

goal2View.setOnClickListener{
    count++
    goalCount.text = count.toString()
}
```